# Store multiple file Using Same Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

File has Data :

```
A 12345
B 32122
C 23232
```

what is the option to run only one time pig script and store first `record(A 12345)` in one file , `second record(B 32122)` in second file and `third(c 23232)` in third file. Right now if we run the pig script it will run the job for each store. Please let me know the option.

Comment: Hi Siva....any comment for the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SPLIT operator to partition the contents of a relation into two or more relations based on some expression. Depending on the conditions stated in the expression:

```
A tuple may be assigned to more than one relation.

A tuple may not be assigned to any relation.
```

Example

In this example relation A is split into three relations, X, Y, and Z.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (f1:int,f2:int,f3:int);

DUMP A;                
(1,2,3)
(4,5,6)
(7,8,9)        

SPLIT A INTO X IF f1<7, Y IF f2==5, Z IF (f3<6 OR f3>6);

DUMP X;
(1,2,3)
(4,5,6)

DUMP Y;
(4,5,6)

DUMP Z;
(1,2,3)
(7,8,9)
```

then STORE X, Y ,Z according to your filename

**My aim is to read a file and write the record in to different files based on criteria** it will fit to your problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, for filtering based store SPLIT is the right option.

Comment: Hi Siva/Kishore. Thanks for the reply.Actually I tried this option using filter, but my main intention is either filter or Split and store X,Y,Z using same one time execution. In the above example, the script will run for 3 times,1 for x , 2nd for y and 3rd for Z. I am trying is there any option, where x,y,z should get stored only in one execution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually pig is not made for this. But still if you wanna do that then will have to write a custom store function. Will have to write some class which extends StoreFunc class. Further inside it will have to use Multiple outputs since you wanna store in 3 different files.

Refer https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Store+Functions for custom store function.

Otherwise in pig, one store command will store only one alias, only in one file.

For such kind of requirement better you write JAVA MR.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **MultiStorage()** option, It will be available in **piggybank jar**. you need to download **pig-0.11.1.jar** and set it in your classpath.

**Example:**
**input.txt**

```
A 12345
B 32122
C 23232
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (f1,f2);
STORE A INTO 'output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('output', '0');
```

Now output folder contains **3 dirs A,B,C** and **filenames(A-0,000 ,B-0,000 and C-0,000 )** contain the actual value
**output$ ls**

```
A       B       C       _SUCCESS
```

**output$ cat A/A-0,000**

```
A   12345
```

**output$ cat B/B-0,000**

```
B   32122
```

**output$ cat C/C-0,000**

```
C   23232
```

Comment: Thank you siva...you mean we can use multistorage to store the records based on some condition. for eg in a file we have a field called age and it has 2 records, one is  17  and another one is 19. if i want store based on this filter age is > 18 in one file and less then or equal to another file. Can we achieve this? i am trying to avoid multiple run.

Comment: This link will help you how to use all the options. https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html

Comment: No, you cant use like that but if found some solution i will update.

Comment: thank you siva. My aim is to read a file and write the record in to  different files based on criteria.based on the above example we can write the record in to 2 files,by using 2 stores, but the script will be executed 2 times. I want to avoid 2 runs and have to achieve the same result in one run. Please update me on the option. THanks a lot.You rock !

Comment: Jagan, you can try the solution provided by kishore. I think it will work for you.